# take two arrays and make a third array from values that are NOT unique

Tags: ruby, duplicates, uniq

I'm attempting to de-dupe an enormous email list migration, however there's a catch.  I'd like to take the duplicates and turn them into their own array (3rd).

Lets make these arrays very simple, and short.

```
a = ["rich@aol.com", "ian@aol.com"]
b = ["rich@aol.com"]
```

Essentially i'm trying to make `c = ["rich@aol.com"]` because it's the only email that resides on both lists.

**What I've attempted so far:**

Is there an opposite to unqiq ?

```
ab = a + b
ab.uniq
```

returns: ["rich@aol.com", "ian@aol.com"]

Could I dump a + b into a third c array, and compare c to ab.uniq to get what's duplicated?

Am i missing an easier way to do this? Any help will be much appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [intersection](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-26) of the arrays.

```
c = a & b
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn a list with carriage returns into an array of strings? ["on]

Comment: Is the list a string, or an array? If it's a string, you can use [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split): `"some string with carriage returns".split(/\r?\n/)`